# EarlyStopping callback behaving mysteriously in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback, keras

My model stops training after the 4th epoch even though I expect it to continue training beyond that. I've set monitor to validation loss and patience to 2, which I thought means that training stops after validation loss increases consecutively for 2 epochs. However, training seems to stop before that happens.

I've defined EarlyStopping as follows:

```
callbacks = [
        EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, verbose=0),
    ]
```

And in the fit function I use it like this:

```
hist = model.fit_generator(
            generator(imgIds, batch_size=batch_size, is_train=True),
            validation_data=generator(imgIds, batch_size=batch_size, is_val=True),
            validation_steps=steps_per_val,
            steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
            epochs=epoch_count,
            verbose=verbose_level,
            callbacks=callbacks)
```

I don't understand why training ends after the 4th epoch.

```
675/675 [==============================] - 1149s - loss: 0.1513 - val_loss: 0.0860
Epoch 2/30
675/675 [==============================] - 1138s - loss: 0.0991 - val_loss: 0.1096
Epoch 3/30
675/675 [==============================] - 1143s - loss: 0.1096 - val_loss: 0.1040
Epoch 4/30
675/675 [==============================] - 1139s - loss: 0.1072 - val_loss: 0.1019
Finished training intermediate1.
```

Comment: What is the val_loss from epoch 1?

Comment: first line - 0.0860 @NicoleWhite

Comment: Oops I see. If anything it should have stopped after epoch 3, as your loss does not improve from epoch 1 in either epoch 2 or 3. Can you set verbose=1 in the callback and show what it says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your interpretation of the `EarlyStopping` callback is a little off; it stops when the loss doesn't improve from *the best loss it has ever seen* for `patience` epochs. The best loss your model had was 0.0860 at epoch 1, and for epochs 2 and 3 the loss did not improve, so it should have stopped training after epoch 3. However, it continues to train for one more epoch due to an off-by-one error, at least I would call it that given what the docs say about `patience`, which is:

> **patience**: number of epochs with no improvement after which training will be stopped.

From the Keras source code (edited slightly for clarity):

```
class EarlyStopping(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current = logs.get(self.monitor)

        if np.less(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
            self.best = current
            self.wait = 0
        else:
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
            self.wait += 1
```

Notice how `self.wait` isn't incremented until *after* the check against `self.patience`, so while your model should have stopped training after epoch 3, it continued for one more epoch.

Unfortunately it seems if you want a callback that behaves the way you described, where it stops training without consecutive improvement in `patience` epochs, you'd have to write it yourself. But I think you could just modify the `EarlyStopping` callback slightly to accomplish this.

Edit: The off-by-one error is [fixed](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/1b53767da71ab94169c60f46f0b8e9d820fd59d5).

Comment: I have to say, it's a shame you changed the implementation and not the docs, because I find `patience=0` to be much more intuitive than `patience=1` for if you want to stop as soon as there is no more improvement (and that's also what e.g. the downhill package does)